# NodeJS return values mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have a question regarding nodeJS.
I have a LOOP in nodeJS that iterates mySQL table and depending on the result executes a specific query.

```
    var query = "SELECT field1,fields2,field3 FROM database.table1";
    mySQLconnection.query(query, function (err, data) {
        if (err)throw err;
        if (data.length != 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
                doFunction1(data[i].field1, data[i].field2, data[i].field3, function (func1data) {
                    if (func1data == false) {
                        doFunction2(data[i].field1, data[i].field2, data[i].field3, function (func2data) {
                            if (func2data == false) {
                                doFunction3(data[i].field1, data[i].field2, data[i].field3, function (func1data) {

                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem with the above approach is that it will not wait for the result from the first doFunction1, but rather it will continue with the i++

Comment: What does `doFunction1` and `doFunction2` do actually?

Comment: They process multiple queries and return result after they've been executed.The reason it is in a loop is because those functions are iterating through the result set and must have only 1 result. This way, they have multiple results because they are async from the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Either of your two functions `doFunction1` or `doFunction2` intiates some kind of asynchronous calls. Looks like you are not familiar with asynchronous behaviour of javascript. You can use the [async.each](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) to handle these type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    some_async_function_call(i);
}
```

Basically this code initiates 10000 requests to execute your asyc functions.  There's no guarantee your code will be executed before the for loop is finished.

What you need to do is to chain your async function calls so it will do things sequentially.  There are multiple ways to achieve this.  For example async.js or bluebird.js

async.js: series, waterfall, parallel... etc
https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

bluebird.js
https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

```
var loop = function(){

    // check loop conditions, return when the loop is finished
    if (finished_loop) return Promise.resolve();

    return Promise.promisify(your_function)()
    .then(loop)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why do you want callbacks here in for loop. Write straight forward code which will be executed sequentially otherwise this code executes asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

At the end i went with a array and counter, when counter reaches the array length, it would restart it self. Basically recursive function.

Thanks for your help